# MonoTouch.Dialog: Search, Querying Database each keystroke

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have enabled search in my MonoTouch.Dialog. After each keystroke I call the database, get the updated list and then re-create the Root. The tableview is always empty though after I regenerate the Root, even though I can confirm that I am adding elements each time.

In a situation where the entire list needs to be recreated each time the user types in the search bar, do I need to recreate the Root each time, or clear it and re-populate it?

I have tried both ways but the tableview never renders anything after I try to regenerate it.

```
    this.SearchTextChanged += (sender, args) => {
             query = args.Text;
            CreateRoot();
        };

    void CreateRoot()
    {
        if(this.Root!=null)
           this.Root.Clear();

        Section section = new Section();
        List<TermItem> terms = LegalDatabase.GetTerms(query, SearchScope);

        foreach (TermItem term in terms)
        {
            var eTerm = new TermElement(term.ID);
            section.Add(eTerm);
        }
        terms = null;
        this.Root.Add(section);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call ReloadData after you make any changes:

```
void CreateRoot ()
{
    ...
    this.Root.ReloadData ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rolf. Such a simple fix to a headache. Works great now.